# Laravel Cron Job not executing in every minute Webuzo

Tags: php, laravel, cron

Cron Job is not working every minute in Webuzo. The following setting has been done in Webuzo Cron:

[image]

when I run the command using ssh in server, it executes for once. The following Laravel code need to be executed in cron:

**Kernel.php**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    $schedule->command('read:hardware')->everyMinute();
}
```

Comment: The issue is not with your code....it is from the hosting cron setup. To achieve the everyMinute() execution your host cron setup should be 
Minute *
Hour  *
Day *
Month *
Weekday * . The spot where you have Minute 1 will make the code execute where the time minutes is at 1

Comment: Achieving the * * * * * cron setup is mostly achieved with VPS servers or exceptional hosting with full cron support

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by setting up cronie in CentOS which is required to install for cron job in CentOS. Following article helped to solve:

http://lampblogs.com/blog/how-to-install-crontab-in-centos?fbclid=IwAR1Uda2UwzI8JFylUmFvPcH5aqGZuVQvv6pfViBv-3GiWOAdUCKibWjY6m8